# Cython: Attribute Error: 'Classes.Vec' object has no attribute 'i'

Tags: python-3.x, cython, attributeerror

I've written a **Vec** class in Cython and used ***pyx*** and ***pxd*** files to implement and define it respectively

Classes.pyx

```
cdef class Vec:
    def __cinit__(self, float i, float j, float k):
        self.i, self.j, self.k = i,j,k
    #more methods...

cdef class line:
    def __cinit__(self,Vec a,Vec b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    #_methods....
```

Classes.pxd

```
cdef class Vec:
    cdef public float i,j,k
    #more_declarations...

cdef class line:
    cdef public Vec a,b
    #more_declarations...
```

When I try to call line, an attribute error is thrown

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
from Classes import line, Vec

L = line(Vec(0,0,4), Vec(5,6,6))
```

I'm new to Cython, your answers would be very helpful

Comment: I'm not convinced it does - `i` is declared (and made public) in the pxd file. I suspect the pxd file isn't being found for some reason

Comment: These files were in the same directory... I also tried to make them private or simply define them without any private or public scope but it was still giving error